# support projection of a sum of positive operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Let $T$ and $S$ be positive selfdjoint bounded operators on a Hilbert space $H$. Let $s(T)$ be the support projection of $T$. Do we have
$$
s(T+S) \geq s(T) ?
$$
(and also $s(T+S) \geq s(S)$)